# How to use autorun with a flow action?

Tags: mobx-state-tree

As in the [docs](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/autorun.html#options) `autorun` can be used to do debounce of a called function, so that last call is the only one that we be called within certain amount of time.

But I cant figure how to use it with an `action` that uses a `flow`, is there any example?

for such example:

```
syncMobileToken: flow(function* syncMobileToken(token) {
      self.isLoading = true 
      let response =  yield cli.post("/notifications/sync_mobile_token", {
        token: token,
        device_id: Config.DEVICE_ID,
      })      
      self.isLoading = false 
    }),
```

how would `autorun` be used with above example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understood your question but my assumtion is that you want to run the method `syncMobileToken` every time `token` changes and to add a delay so the method is not run every keypress or other event triggers.

If so then you could take advantage of the `afterCreate` lifecycle method of the model

```
myModel = types.model({}).actions(self => ({
  afterCreate() {

    addDisposer(self, 
      reaction(() => ({
          token: self.token
      }), () => { 
        await self.syncMobileToken(self.token)
      },{
        delay: 200
      })
    )
  }

}))
```

You need to wrap the reaction in a addDisposer so that the reaction stops firing when the model is destroyed/removed.

This is my prefered way to use. I don't usually use `autorun` to be honest.

If my answer doesn't solve your issue please give more detailes on what you are trying to achive using the autorun.

Comment: seem like: it will sync after each 0.2s, even the data is still changing in client